# CakePHP 2.3 form not showing validation errors

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, cakephp

I have been trying to debug this for about two days and have read every answer to this question on the internet... and still can't get it to work.

In my CakePHP app I have a user sign-up form, which uses a model called *User* and the *Form* helper. When validation fails, the form does not show any of the validation errors.

The `$this->User->validationErrors` array is properly populated before the view is rendered, according to `debug()`, and the fact that the model does not validate is detected by `$this->User->save()`.

Here's my view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('soton_username', array('label' => 'Email address', 'after' => '@soton.ac.uk'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Choose a username'));
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('label' => 'Password (again)', 'type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
echo $this->Form->submit('Create account');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Here's my action:

```
public function create() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

        $valid = true;
        $validationErrors = array();
        $password = $this->request->data('User.password');
        $password_confirm = $this->request->data('User.password_confirm');

        if(strlen($password) < 5) {
            $validationErrors['password'][] = 'Password must be at least 5 characters long';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if($password != $password_confirm) {
            $validationErrors['password_confirm'][] ='Passwords do not match';
            $valid = false;
        }

        $this->User->data['User']['email'] = $this->request->data('User.soton_username') . '@soton.ac.uk';

        $group = $this->Group->find('first', array('conditions' => array('default' => 1)));
        if($group) {
            $gid = $group['Group']['id'];
        } else {
            $gid = 1;
        }
        $this->User->data['User']['group_id'] = $gid;

        if($this->User->validates() && $valid) {
            $this->User->save();
            $this->Session->setFlash('<a href="/users/activate/' . $this->User->data['User']['activation_id'] . '">Activate</a>');
            return $this->redirect('/users/confirm_create');
        }

        $this->User->validationErrors = array_merge($this->User->validationErrors, $validationErrors);

        if(isset($this->User->validationErrors['email'])) {
            $this->User->validationErrors['soton_username'] = $this->User->validationErrors['email'];
        }

        //debug($this->request->validationErrors);exit;
        $this->Session->setFlash('There were errors with the form.');
    }
}
```

The *soton_username* and *password_confirm* fields are not actually part of the database, but still need to be validated.

My *User* model does have a `$validate` variable which *Form* does recognise as it inserts `required="required"` in the right places.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I've found the answer to my question.

The following function in my *AppController* class is the culrprit:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $user = $this->User->read(null, $user_id);
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

For some reason, calling the `$this->Model->read()` function prevents validation errors from being displayed, and this function was being calling this at the end of every action. Moving it to the `beforeFilter()` function fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue.  BTW, you can use AuthComponent::user() in views, so no need for that code in beforeFilter()

Comment: Fixed my issue too, 8 months later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer, since I was not calling User->read():

I dug through cake's core and found that the error fields are auto-populated based on the model name passed with form->create('model').

My model is 'User', and in my view I had $this->form->create('Users'). Notice the 's'.
Validation is done on the model, so the validation error array is indexed by the model name: 'User'. The form uses the name passed in create, 'Users', to search for the errors.

To fix this, make sure you use the singular form of the model in form->create(). For me that is 'User'.

Comment: I had to post this because all I could find on the internet were people talking about calling read(). Hope this helps someone.